# Which is the best way to list tickets that do not change lane / status in JIRA?

Tags: jira, process, development-process, process-controls

my goal is to have a list of the JIRA tickets that are not moving from one lane to another so that I can intervene on those tickets and check if impediments, difficulties or issues are up in place.

So basically I would like a query to create a JIRA **filter** that sort tickets depending on some ticket information, for example

- sort the amount of time since *last date status changed*
- sort the amount of time spent in the *status "IN PROGRESS", in "REVIEW" or in "TESTING"* (where IN PROGRESS, REVIEW, TESTING are status within my JIRA project)

If it is not possible to create a specific query/filter, which could be the other solutions? I am already aware of the grey-gradient-coloured-dots in the bottom part of the ticket within the Active Sprint view. But I prefer to visualize this information out of a query, for example for a dashboard widget.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to *sort* by status changed date. However, given that your requirement is "to have a list of the JIRA tickets that are not moving from one lane to another so that I can intervene on those tickets", you can find all tickets that have not moved in X days. For example:

(status = "In Progress" AND status changed to "In Progress" before "-7d") OR (status = "To Do" AND status changed to "To Do" before "-7d") OR ...

Just add one (status = "STATUSNAME" AND status changed to "STATUSNAME" before "-7d") for each status you want to track and change the 7 to the number of days you want an issue to sit idle before it shows up on the filter.

Comment: I think this is going to work perfectly for my need. Thanks @Sarov

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by time in status in an issue filter. The query would look like:
project = My project and status = "tracked status" order by "[CHART] Time in Status".

This will show the list of issues in the right project and status, with the one that has spent the most time in that status at the top of the list.